# Android Studio doesn't see devices (usb and emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Android studio doesn't see any of the devices, but it worked before. Now, when real device is connected via USB and I can see all it's files from the PC, Android Studio still doesn't see it, no matter this exactly device worked a few months ago with this exactly PC. The same situation with emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an update of my antivirus (Avast). Somehow it decided to block adb.exe. That is why none of my devices were recognized by Android Studio. By opening the antivirus and deleting adb.exe from the quarantine I could solve the problem.